# C programming - 1's complement of End of File

Tags: c, eof

To start off, I am a novice in C.

I stumbled across an example, which asked the user to decrypt a c-file (which contains 1's complement of another c-file).

Normally, you would copy the characters using the following statement

```
    while ((ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
```

but I am having trouble, while decrypting the file. I tried the following -

```
    while (~(ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
```

the result is - the program is going into indefinite loop. I tried using the ASCII value of EOF (which is 26), but even that didn't work in my favor.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

/* program to decrypt the file */

Here is the full code -

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    void main()
    {
        FILE *fs, *ft;
        char ch;

        fs = fopen("xyz.c", "r");
        ft = fopen("xyz1.c", "w");

        if((fs == NULL) || (ft == NULL))
        {
            printf("Cannot open the file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while (~(ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
            fputc(~ch, ft);

        fclose(fs);
        fclose(ft);
    }
```

Comment: `EOF` isn't a character.  It's a stream state and `getchar()` will return `EOF` once a read has failed due to hitting the end of the file.  It won't be part of what you're decrypting (i.e. you don't need to complement it)

Comment: Update your question to show the actual code you're using. `while (((~ch) = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)` won't compile; you can't have `(~ch)` on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: How did you declare `ch` ?

Comment: I have updated the question with my code. black answered it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOF is a marker that signals that the end of file (or stream) has been reached. Now, such marker is not handled by you - you *cannot* modify it (or encrypt it, in this case), since it's internally managed by the underlying file system.

Therefore, checking for `~EOF` is logically wrong and will only catch that specific value (`EOF` is `-1` on most implementations, so `~-1` is `0`).

Simply:

```
int ch;
while ( (ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF )
    int decoded = ~ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the value returned to `fgetc(fs)` to `EOF`. Only apply the `~` operator to it *after* you've done that comparison.

And applying `~` to the result of `fgetc()` is going to cause problems. For example, if you read the letter `'a'`, the value of `ch` (which needs to be an `int`, not `char`) is going to be `97` (assuming an ASCII-based system). `~97` is going to be a very large negative number, probably somewhere around -2 billion. You'll need to grab just the low-order bits of the result.

Comment: Thank You, Keith.. but as "black" pointed out -> 

EOF is a marker and is internally managed.. so I should use with the same first while loop for comparing EOF and use 1st complement for rest of the characters inside while loop. It works for me. 

Thanks though

Comment: @Ashish: Yes, that's pretty much what I said.

Comment: My bad. I didn't understand your comment at first go. Thanks though :)